# Как выбрать вариант сортировки или как вывести каждый вариант отсортированной таблицы?

Tags: sql

Есть задание:

"1 процедура
выводит список населенных пунктов (по умолчанию сортировка по названию страны + название пункта)
с возможностями:

- сортировать по номеру и/или индексу и/или названию и/или району и/или региону и/или стране           +
- фильтр по индексу и/или названию и/или району и/или региону и/или стране"

Я понимаю как отсортировать таблицу с сортировкой по умолчанию. Но как именно я должен добавить возможности (варианты сортировки) я не понимаю.

Может быть я должен вывести каждый вариант отсортированной таблицы ? Но тогда, как именно это сделать, если процедура останавливается после первого запроса SELECT ?

Код:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "test"."first_proc"( /* @parameter_name parameter_type [= default_value] 
[OUTPUT], ... */ )
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT Id, Ind, populated_areas.Name, Area, Region, populated_areas.code, countries.name FROM 
    populated_areas
    INNER JOIN countries ON populated_areas.code = countries.code
    ORDER BY countries.name, populated_areas.name

    SELECT Id, Ind, populated_areas.Name, Area, Region, populated_areas.code, countries.name FROM 
    populated_areas
    INNER JOIN countries ON populated_areas.code = countries.code
    ORDER BY populated_areas.ind
END
```

Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Тут имеется ввиду, что процедура должна принимать параметры, которые определяют по какому полю(полям) сортировать, и по какому полю(полям) фильтровать. В зависимости от переданных параметров, процедура должна вывести результат.

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь я понял